# How can I internally redirect with Mojo?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

Catalyst supported redirects internal to the framework ([`forward`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst#$c-%3Eforward(-$action-[,-@arguments-]-)) and [`detach`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst#$c-%3Edetach(-$action-[,-@arguments-]-))), and external (HTTP) redirects (`res->redirect)`. Internal redirects essentially just redispatched to a new path,

Lets say I set up two paths,

```
sub register ( $self, $app, $conf ) {
    my $r = $app->routes;
    $r->any( 'foo',  => \&foo_baz );
    $r->any( 'bar',  => \&bar_baz );
}
```

How would I tell `foo` after it does some stuff, to internally redirect to `bar`?

```
sub foo_baz ($c) {
  ; stuff
  bar_baz($c)
}
```

Is there a better way than calling `bar_baz($c)` directly? These routes are declared in a Mojo Plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discussed on IRC, but: Mojolicious does not support the dynamic routing of internal redirects as Catalyst does. The common suggestion is to abstract out your code to avoid duplication while not directly calling another route. So instead of route A calling route B, both of them would call a helper or method to complete the common functionality using their current controller object.